# Why am I geting TypeError: onSuccess is not a function in my angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs services that leverages restangular to make calls.

```js
angular.module('app.userSvc', [])
    .factory('userSvc', ['localStorageService', '$rootScope', 'Restangular',
        function(localStorageService, $rootScope, Restangular) {
            function checkIfLoggedIn() {
                return localStorage.getItem('token');
            }

            function login(email, password, onSuccess, onError) {
                Restangular.all('api/authenticate')
                    .post({
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    })
                    .then(
                        function(response) {
                            localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
                            onSuccess(response);
                        },
                        function(response) {
                            onError(response);
                        });
            }

            function logout() {
                localStorageService.remove('token');
            }

            function getCurrentToken() {
                return localStorage.getItem('token');
            }

            function getAuthenticatedUser(onSuccess, onError) {
                Restangular.one('api/authenticated_user?token=' + getCurrentToken()).get().then(function(response) {
                    onSuccess(response.user);
                }, function(response) {
                    onError(response);
                });
            }
            Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getCurrentToken()
            });
            return {
                checkIfLoggedIn: checkIfLoggedIn,
                login: login,
                logout: logout,
                getCurrentToken: getCurrentToken,
                getAuthenticatedUser: getAuthenticatedUser
            };
        }
    ]);
```

But when i call the userSvc.getAuthenticatedUser() method in a controller i get TypeError: onSuccess is not a function
This is how am calling it.

```js
console.log(userSvc.getAuthenticatedUser());
```

What am i doing wrong. I am using angular 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is expected, As your service method expected callback method so pass them

```
function getAuthenticatedUser(onSuccess, onError){
}
```

So you need to pass the callback methods

```
userSvc.getAuthenticatedUser(function() {}, function() {})
```

---

Or, You can check whether argument is defined and a [angular.isFunction](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isFunction)

```
function getAuthenticatedUser(onSuccess, onError) {
    Restangular.one('api/authenticated_user?token=' + getCurrentToken()).get().then(function (response) {
        !!onSuccess && angular.isFunction(onSuccess) && onSuccess(response.user);
    }, function (response) {
        !!onError && angular.isFunction(onError) &&
        onError(response);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You HAVE to set a callback function as the first argument, because inside `getAuthenticatedUser()`, there is no check to see whether the `onSuccess` argument is set or not. (The same is actually true for the onError callback, so you need to provide that second argument, too)

So, either implement such a check (e.g. `onSuccess && onSuccess()`) inside the `getAuthenticatedUser` function, or provide a callback function (even if it's an anonymous one that doesn't to anything) in order to prevent that error.

```
userSvc.getAuthenticatedUser(function() {}, function() {});
```